# Radeon HD7900 driver?

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon, fglrx

What driver should I get for this graphics card? I attempted installing the standard one for Linux on AMD's site.. Boy was that a mess. Had to reinstall my entire system for it!

Any suggestions?

Comment: sudo lshw provides me

Comment: product: Tahiti PRO [Radeon HD 7950/8950 OEM / R9 280]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]

Answer (score 0):

Just fo to System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional drivers

and install suggested driver from there.

Or run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

This is not an Ubuntu way to download video drivers from sites.

But sometimes proprietary drivers have bugs and incompatibilities. If system does not load GUI, you do not have to re-install.

Start console with Ctrl+Alt+F1, login there and run

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
```

to revert it.

Comment: That won't install the standard AMD driver again which killed my system?

I'll try it out. Thanks.

Comment: That will install really standard in Ubuntu driver.

Comment: It still installs the AMD driver. The default `radeon` driver should work in most situations though.

Comment: @Pilot6 I actually uninstalled the fglrx with your command since steam gave me an error. I tried your first option, and without anything, it says the x-org ATI/AMD driver is in use... So it's all good then?

Comment: Add output pf `lspci -k | grep VGA -A2` to your question